# Failed to run controller

Tags: angularjs, controller, ionic-framework

I have a problem with running my controller after declaring it.

This is my current code:
app.js

```
var myApp = angular.module('starter', ['ionic']);
myApp.controller ("venueCtrl", function() {
     this.test = [];
     for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        this.test.push(i);
     };
     console.log("123");
})
```

index.html

```
<body ng-app="starter">
    <ion-nav-bar class="bar-stable">
        <ion-nav-back-button></ion-nav-back-button>
    </ion-nav-bar>

    <ion-nav-view></ion-nav-view>
</body>
```

tab-view.html (the template that I am editing)

```
<ion-view title = "Venue" ng-controller="venueCtrl as main">
    <ion-list>
       <ion-item collection-repeat="item in main.test">
           {{item}}
      </ion-item>
    </ion-list>
</ion-view>
```

What I am trying to do is just listing a list of number from 1 to 100 using collection-repeat. I use console.log to show some debug (I am using serve --lab with console option on). However, the console doesn't show anything. I have tested already to see that the console is working (I put console.log outside of the declaration of the controller). So now I am not so sure what's wrong since I have checked some sources and the controller declaring seems correct to me. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Did you include the necessary angular files?

Comment: I don't have idea about ionic .. I have demonstrated a [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/lA0ca1VVT0vyvSjYMljJ?p=preview) for your task do check it. I hope it helps you.

Comment: Is the AngularUI router configured to load the correct view and controller?  If the controller is never loaded, the logging statement will not be run. I see you're using the Ionic example project. I'd suggest comparing your code to the unedited example code and see what's different.

Comment: Please, read the [documentation](http://ionicframework.com/getting-started/).